# CloudKit Sync on M1 Mac Mini

Tags: core-data, cloudkit, mac-catalyst

I have just released an update to one of my apps now using CloudKit and CoreData. The app runs on iOS and macOS using mac-catalyst. I got an email from one of my users who is using a M1 Mac Mini saying that the records he ads on the Mac is not synced to his iPhone but records added with the iPhone does show up on his Mac.

I have tested the app on a MacBook pro still running Catalina as well as MacBook Air on Big Sur with 3 different Apple ID's and iOS devises and records sync without any issues whether they are created on the iOS device or Mac. I do not have access to any M1 hardware so I am not sure if somehow they behave differently to the Intel versions when it comes to CloudKit sync. There does seem to be a lot of complaints online about iCloud drive sync and the M1 Macs but I haven't found anything specifically mentioning CloudKit and CoreData. Did anyone else here have similar reports from users? Is there any settings in a M1 Mac that could prevent CloudKit to sync?

Would appreciate any help with this. Thanks